# Как найти строки по шаблону, в которых нет определенной строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте. Нужно найти все ссылки, у которых домен НЕ mysite.com
А у меня получился поиск всех ссылок, у которых домен mysite.com. Как исправить?

```
$r = preg_match("/href=[\"']http:\/\/(www\.)*(mysite\.com)/i", $ret);
```

Comment: Забыла написать. Вообще-то я делаю preg_replace, но и он у меня криво работает, потому временно взяла preg_match и пока вчера до ночи ковырялась, совершенно об этом забыла :)
Мне нужно сделать, чтобы правильно работала регулярка для preg_replace

Comment: То есть, вы хотите при помощи preg_replace сделать следующее: если $ret не соответствует регулярному выражению, то этот $ret заменить на другую строку. Думаю, у вас этого не получится. Функции поиска по регулярным выражениям ищут вхождения соответствия этим регулярным выражениям, а не их отсутствия. То есть использовать отрицание регулярного выражения не получится (может быть кто-то меня поправит). Используйте: if(!preg_match("/href=[\"']http:\/\/(www\.)*(mysite\.com)/i", $ret)) $ret='Другой урл';

Comment: UP: Хотя, если хотите использовать preg_replace, то попробуйте покопать в сторону правила для регулярных выражений - "Если первый символ в скобках это ^ - значит ни один из указанных символов не может стоять в данном месте выражения." Например, [^abc] соответствует любому символу, кроме «a», «b» или «c».

Answer (score 1):

## DOMDocument + DOMXPath

Надежнее всего при работе с размеченным текстом использовать специально для этого созданный парсер. Основа этого кода - XPath-выражение `'//*[@href and not(starts-with(@href, "http://mysite.com")) and not(starts-with(@href, "http://www.mysite.com"))]'`, которое получает все элементы с атрибутом `href`, значение которого не начинается с `http://mysite.com` и `http://www.mysite.com`.

[PHP-код](http://ideone.com/qvgHsy):

```
$html = <<<DATA
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">text</a>
<a href="http://mysite.com">text1</a>
<a href='http://mysite.com'>text2</a>
<a href='http://www.mysite.com'>text3</a>
<a href='http://www.hissite.com'>text4</a>
<a href="http://www.moon.com/id.php?site=mysite.com">text5</a>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//*[@href and not(starts-with(@href, "http://mysite.com")) and not(starts-with(@href, "http://www.mysite.com"))]');

$res_arr = array();
foreach($links as $link) { 
   array_push($res_arr, $link->getAttribute('href'));
}
print_r($res_arr);
```

## Регулярное выражение

Регулярное выражение, которое проверяет наличие `http://mysite.com` сразу после открывающей (двойной) кавычки и, если не находит, возвращает совпадение. Для удобства использована именная захватывающая подмаска `(?<link>(?:(?!\1).)*)`.

```
\bhref=(["'])(?!http:\/\/(?:www\.)*mysite\.com)(?<link>(?:(?!\1).)*)
```

См. [демо выражения](https://regex101.com/r/nM2yY9/2)

[PHP-код](http://ideone.com/1Qfb4m):

```
$re = '~\bhref=(["\'])(?!http://(?:www\.)*mysite\.com)(?<link>(?:(?!\1).)*)~i'; 
$str = "<a href=\"http://www.mysite.com\">\n<a href=\"http://mysite.com\">\n<a href='http://mysite.com'>\n<a href='http://www.mysite.com'>\n<a href='http://www.hissite.com'>\n<a href='http://www.moon.com/id.php?site=mysite.com'>"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["link"]);
```

Comment: На всякий случай добавлю, что `(?:(?!\1).)*` находит любую подстроку, в которой отсутствует либо `'`, либо `"` (то, что найдёт первая захватывающая подмаска). Это называется [*greedy tempered token* ("жадный" "умеренный" квантификатор) - *англ.*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed)

Answer (score 0):

Прямо с сайта php.su со страницы описания функции preg_match:

```
if (preg_match("/href=[\"']http:\/\/(www\.)*(mysite\.com)/i", $ret)){
    echo 'Вхождение найдено';
} else {
    echo 'Вхождение не найдено';
}
```

То есть, вам нужно:

```
if (!preg_match("/href=[\"']http:\/\/(www\.)*(mysite\.com)/i", $ret))
    echo 'Вхождение не найдено';
```

Comment: Пардон, моя ошибка... Добавила комментарий выше :)